# How can we compare distributions?

Tags: discussion, questions, question-quality

As You know, there is everlasting question (especially from beginners): "what is best (GNU/Linux) distribution?".

Those threads are always closed as opinion based and beginners are left on their own or to blindly trust random people's opinion.

I was wondering, if is it possible to group by some set of criterion, that are:

1. helpful (especially for beginners) when choosing distribution for self
2. based on facts (so no one can call them opinion-based)

Is it possible to compose such criteria?

If yes - what are those criteria?
If no - why is it impossible?

How can we solve this problem once and for all?

Comment: No problem to solve.

Answer (score 1):

“What is the best distribution?” is too broad. There isn't a single best distribution. You are not going to solve this problem once and for all. We have a whole [tag](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/distribution-choice) about the topic, it can't be contained in a single question.

There may be a best distribution *for a specific use case*. I recommend [my guidelines about asking for software recommendations](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information). I've rarely seen a good [distribution-choice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/distribution-choice) question, but it's possible.

“Beginner” is not a specific use case. What are you going to do with your computer? What are you already familiar with? What do other people around you use? These are important questions and people have very different answers to those, beginner or not.